# Randomly get strings from a database using python

Tags: random

I have saved questions in a MySQL database. I want to fetch those questions randomly. How I can do this using Python?

Following is the what I have done so far.

Code:

```
def get_questions():
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                 user="root",         
                 passwd="",           
                 db="questionsbank")  

cur = db.cursor()

preferred_area = get_preferred_area()

if preferred_area == 'Java':
    cur.execute("SELECT question from java_questions")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use random module follow this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html
cur.fetchall return a list
with random module you use choice feature.

Comment: Thanks...I was able to find a solution after going through this